# How to bind components to component after using forwardRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component, react-forwardref

I need bind `Title` and `Body` components to Wrapper component.

Before, I wrote my component like this:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';

// need bound components
const Title: FC<...> = () => {...}
const Body: FC<...> = () => {...}

interface WrapperProps{...}
interface WrapperInterface extends FC<WrapperProps>{
  Title: typeof Title // bind Title component
  Body: typeof Body // bind Body Component
}
const Wrapper: WrapperInterface = () => {...}

Wrapper.Title = Title;
Wrapper.Body = Body;
```

After using `forwardRef`, I modified `WrapperInterface`, But typescript always prompts me that I am missing `Title` and `Body` properties, this is the `WrapperInterface` code:

```js
import { ForwardRefExoticComponent, RefAttributes, forwardRef } from 'react'

// need bound components
const Title: FC<...> = () => {...}
const Body: FC<...> = () => {...}

interface WrapperRef{...}
interface WrapperProps{...}
interface WrapperInstance extends ForwardRefExoticComponent<WrapperProps & RefAttributes<WrapperRef>>{
  Title: typeof Title // bind Title component
  Body: typeof Body // bind Body Component
}

const Wrapper: WrapperInstance = forwardRef((props, ref) => {...});
// TS2739: Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent  >' is missing the following properties from type 'WrapperInterface': Title, Body
Wrapper.Title = Title;
Wrapper.Body = Body;
```

Not directly exported because the `Body` and `Title` components are too common.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this github issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34757) and [the solution reported in it](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34757#issuecomment-488848720), you can solve the above problem by typecasting the component as WrapperInstance like

```
import { ForwardRefExoticComponent, RefAttributes, forwardRef } from 'react'

// need bound components
const Title: FC<...> = () => {...}
const Body: FC<...> = () => {...}

interface WrapperRef{...}
interface WrapperProps{...}
interface WrapperInstance extends ForwardRefExoticComponent<WrapperProps & RefAttributes<WrapperRef>>{
  Title: typeof Title // bind Title component
  Body: typeof Body // bind Body Component
}

const Wrapper = forwardRef<WrapperRef, WrapperProps>((props, ref) => {...}) as WrapperInstance;
Wrapper.Title = Title;
Wrapper.Body = Body;
```